# How can I convert a series of images to a PDF from the command line on Linux?

Tags: image, bash, pdf

I have a scanning server I wrote in CGI and Bash. I want to be able to convert a bunch of images (all in one folder) to a PDF from the command line. How can that be done?

Comment: See also [How to generate a PDF from a series of images?](http://superuser.com/questions/687849/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-a-series-of-images) on superuser.

Comment: Related: [Converting multiple image files from JPEG to PDF format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29869/21471) at unix SE

Comment: Use [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf), not ImageMagick. ImageMagick decodes the JPEG, resulting in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) and is 10–100 times slower than img2pdf.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gscan2pdf` 
for simple and easy use.

Comment: `img2pdf $(find . -iname '*.jpg' | sort -V) -o ./document.pdf` will give you `document.pdf` containing all images with jpg or JPG extension in the current dir - one image per page. `document.pdf` will have all images ordered as pages naturally (`-V` option for `sort`) so there is no need to add any leading zeros when numbering image files.

Comment: I've asked and answered a [very similar question on SoftwareRecs.SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/60187/15631).

Comment: @Jimmix I got an error `invalid rotation(0)`.

Comment: @philoopher97 Perhaps this is due to unknown value in the Exif that relates to the picture orientation (landscape/portrait). You may try to remove that value by removing whole Exif [link](https://linuxnightly.com/how-to-remove-exif-data-via-linux-command-line/) or look for other software to edit that value. [Exif orientation values](https://sirv.com/help/articles/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/)

Comment: See also: [Ask Ubuntu: Create a single pdf from multiple text, images or pdf files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303849/create-a-single-pdf-from-multiple-text-images-or-pdf-files/1385947). I've added [an answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385947/327339) which does OCR in the process.

Answer (score 508, accepted):

Using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), you can try:

```
convert page.png page.pdf
```

For multiple images:

```
convert page*.png mydoc.pdf
```

Comment: what if page*.png does not sort the images in the way you want ? e.g. page_1.png, page_2.png ... page_10.png -> page_10 will appear before page_1

Comment: If not sort - sort himself and create own list.

Comment: That's nice but how to sort files while making the pdf file?

Comment: To sort the files, you can use: `ls page*.png | sort -n | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\ mydoc.pdf/' | xargs convert`

Comment: FYI you *almost* never need to use `ls` for anything apart from displaying files... i.e. do not parse it's output. `find` is a much more suitable tool. Here is an example `convert $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'page*.png' | sort -n | paste -sd\ ) output.pdf`. Keep in mind that the aforementioned command will not work if your pathnames contain spaces. The addition of characters that need to be escaped makes things a little more complicated.

Comment: On my machine `convert` rapidly consumes all available memory (that's 8Gb of RAM), hangs the entire system and kills KDE. The only way out is `ctrl+alt+f1` and `sudo reboot`. Doesn't look like the best solution to me.

Comment: the order is not working for me

Comment: This is simple and works very well, thank you! To avoid generating huge PDF files, use something like `convert -compress jpeg -quality 85 *.png out.pdf`

Comment: When converting multiple files, `convert` consumed all available disk space then failed so I converted them into separate pdf files and joined using `pdfunite`.

Comment: ImageMagick decodes the JPEG, resulting in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Use [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf) instead; it's also 10–100 times faster.

Comment: `ls` [can do the sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279329/1959808).

Comment: @GaloisPlusPlus a more advanced sorting methods: `sort --version-sort` _natural sort of (version) numbers within text_.  That will correctly sort things like 1.2.3, 1.22.2, 1.222.0

Comment: How to reduce the size of the output pdf file? The generated pdf file has almost size of all the images combined.

Comment: I got `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.`

Comment: You can shorten @GaloisPlusPlus using: `ls page*.png | sort -n | xargs -I % convert % mydoc.pdf`

Answer (score 92):

Use [`img2pdf`](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) instead of `convert` from [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/). For example:

```
img2pdf im1.png im2.jpg -o out.pdf
```

To include all `.jpg` images in the current working directory:

```
img2pdf *.jpg -o out.pdf
```

---

**Why `img2pdf` vs. `convert`**?

To summarise comments, ImageMagick's `convert`:

- decodes the JPEG resulting in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss);
- is slower than `img2pdf`;
- requires PDF creation to be enabled (off by default) due to security issues; and
- has issues/limitations when handling large/many images.

Comment: ImageMagick decodes the JPEG, resulting in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Use [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf) instead; it's also 10–100 times faster.

Comment: Note: img2pdf has moved to https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf.

Comment: @RobertFleming, Kelvin, your suggestions are awesome, too bad we cannot add them as a proper answer to this thread. Cheers

Comment: To install: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install img2pdf`

Comment: I have an [issue open](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/issues/23) in my [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) project to allow images to be used as inputs too, so they can be converted to searchable PDFs via `tesseract`. Meanwhile, I've used your answer in my work-around.

Comment: There are so many more problems with `convert`. Due to security problems, PDF creation is disabled by default and needs to turned on in a config file. It even crashes when concatenating between 100 and 200 images (at about 10 MiB PDF size) due to "exhausted cache memory", requiring the user to implement a loop and later concatenating the PDFs, it's very stupid. Also, the resulting PDF with `convert` wastes more memory than `img2pdf`. But still unbelievable, that `img2pdf` is not installed by default on Ubuntu.