# Merge multiple JPGs into single PDF in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I used the following command to convert and merge all the JPG files in a directory to a single PDF file:

```
convert *.jpg file.pdf
```

The files in the directory are numbered from `1.jpg` to `123.jpg`. The conversion went fine but after converting, the pages were all mixed up. I wanted the PDF to have pages from `1.jpg` to `123.jpg` in the same order as they are named. I tried it with the following command as well:

```
cd 1
FILES=$( find . -type f -name "*jpg" | cut -d/ -f 2)
mkdir temp && cd temp
for file in $FILES; do
    BASE=$(echo $file | sed 's/.jpg//g');
    convert ../$BASE.jpg $BASE.pdf;
    done && 
pdftk *pdf cat output ../1.pdf &&
cd ..
rm -rf temp
```

But still no luck. Operating system is Linux.

Comment: Adding a comment on behalf of user sindhus, who didn't have the sufficient points to comment (see below): the `convert` command is a part of the `imagemagick` package.

Comment: error: convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF'

Comment: if you encounter a security policy issue, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1081907/281163

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is because your shell is expanding the wildcard in a purely alphabetical order, and because the lengths of the numbers are different, the order will be incorrect:

```
$ echo *.jpg
1.jpg 10.jpg 100.jpg 101.jpg 102.jpg ...
```

The solution is to pad the filenames with zeros as required so they're the same length before running your convert command:

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do num=`expr match "$i" '\([0-9]\+\).*'`;
> padded=`printf "%03d" $num`; mv -v "$i" "${i/$num/$padded}"; done
```

Now the files will be matched by the wildcard in the correct order, ready for the convert command:

```
$ echo *.jpg
001.jpg 002.jpg 003.jpg 004.jpg 005.jpg 006.jpg 007.jpg 008.jpg ...
```

Comment: I have created an `sh` file with your code. But it is showing the following error while running:
`rename.sh: 2: rename.sh: Bad substitution`

Comment: Are you using bash? If so, which version?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: How are you executing the script? Using `source` or `.`, or with a shebang line? Have you tried simply executing the code directly in the interactive shell?

Comment: `sh` is almost always not the same thing as `bash`. It is usually the plain Bourne shell, or `bash` running in a special Bourne-emulation mode. Either way, the syntax for `sh` can be quite different sometimes. I'd suggest using `bash rename.sh` instead.

Comment: @Harikrishnan T. "Bad substitution", with no other relevant information can be caused by an encoding issue. For example if you have Windows end-of-line (CR/LF)

Answer (score 172):

From the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) of `ls`:

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

So, doing what we need in a single command:

```
convert $(ls -v *.jpg) foobar.pdf
```

Mind that `convert` is part of [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick).

Comment: @Jason: It works (+1). But did you eventually forget that most digital cameras store their images as `*.JPG` and not as `*.jpg`?

Comment: Failing when filenames has a whitespace in them, except from that thumb up! : ))

Comment: Note that this is a feature of GNU ls, not BSD ls. Install GNU coreutils to get GNU ls on the BSD family and OS X.

Comment: Another good one if you generated your images in order is to sort by modification time with `ls -t` flag. Also, the `-r` flag reverses the order.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. However, when I tried it, it failed due to this error: `convert-im6.q16: not authorized `foobar.pdf'`. Evidently, this is a security issue, which can be resolved via this thread - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert

Comment: To convert a lot of high quality images, I had to change the convert policy on disk memory to avoid a exhausting cache resources: https://github.com/phw/peek/issues/112

Comment: As @ArturGower said, for those who will experience something like this:

`convert-im6.q16: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c/ConnectPixelCacheServer/244. `
`convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted './foo256.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3984. `
[Here is](https://github.com/phw/peek/issues/112#issuecomment-332132474) the line that has to be changed and why

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
convert '%d.jpg[1-132]' file.pdf
```

via https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php:

> Another method of referring to other image files is by embedding a
>   formatting character in the filename with a scene range. Consider the
>   filename `image-%d.jpg[1-5]`. The command
>
> `magick image-%d.jpg[1-5]` causes ImageMagick to attempt to read images
>   with these filenames:
>
> `image-1.jpg image-2.jpg image-3.jpg image-4.jpg image-5.jpg`

See also https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Answer (score 5):

All of the above answers failed for me, when I wanted to merge many high-resolution jpeg images (from a scanned book).

Imagemagick tried to load all files into RAM, I therefore used the following two-step approach:

```
find -iname "*.JPG" | xargs -I'{}' convert {} {}.pdf
pdfunite *.pdf merged_file.pdf
```

Note that with this approach, you can also use GNU parallel to speed up the conversion:

```
find -iname "*.JPG" | parallel -I'{}' convert {} {}.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:
First line convert all jpg files to pdf it is using convert command.
Second line is merging all pdf files to one single as pdf per page. This is using gs ((PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer))

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -print); do convert $i ${i//jpg/pdf}; done
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=merged_file.pdf -dBATCH `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -print"`
```

Answer (score 3):

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

In all of the proposed solutions involving ImageMagick, the JPEG data gets fully decoded and re-encoded. This results in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), as well as performance "ten to hundred" times worse than img2pdf.

img2pdf is also available from many Linux distros, as well as via pip3.

Comment: Plus, using ImageMagick can be a hassle due to security policies preventing it's convenient use.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing first idea with their reply, I think this code maybe satisfactory

```
jpgs2pdf.sh

#!/bin/bash

cd $1
FILES=$( find . -type f -name "*jpg" | cut -d/ -f 2)
mkdir temp > /dev/null
cd temp

for file in $FILES; do
 BASE=$(echo $file | sed 's/.jpg//g');
 convert ../$BASE.jpg $BASE.pdf;
done &&

pdftk `ls -v *pdf` cat output ../`basename $1`.pdf
cd ..
rm -rf temp
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to create A PDF document from a list of images**

> Step 1: Install `parallel` from Repository. This will speed up the process

> Step 2: Convert each jpg to pdf file

```
find -iname "*.JPG" | sort -V | parallel -I'{}' convert -compress jpeg -quality 25 {} {}.pdf
```

The `sort -V` will sort the file names in natural order.

> Step 3: Merge all PDFs into one

```
pdfunite $(find -iname '*.pdf' | sort -V) output_document.pdf
```

*Credit [Gregor Sturm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815792/8229399)*

Answer (score -1):

Combining Felix Defrance's and Delan Azabani's answer(from above):

```sh
convert `for file in $FILES; do echo $file; done` test_2.pdf
```