# Script to merge all image files from a folder inside a pdf

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, imagemagick-convert

I frequently have to merge a lot of images inside a pdf. Naturally, I'd like to automate this a bit.

Here are the things I need:

- lossless merge into a pdf
- merge of most common image formats
- natural sorting of numbers (`1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, and `10.jpg` would be merged in this order, not as `1.jpg` `10.jpg` `2.jpg`)
- can deal with white-spaces in file names

I've come across a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279329) that works exactly like I'd need it to, but which fails for files containing a white-space in their name.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
convert `ls -v *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG *.png *.PNG *.gif *.GIF *.tiff *.TIFF *.webp *.WEBP *.bmp *.BMP` compilation_images.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Trying to parse `ls` is wrong](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), as you've found out. Assuming you're using GNU versions of utilities as the linux tag usually implies, try something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Turn on case-insensitive globs and make ones that
# don't match anything expand to nothing
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob

readarray -d '' -t images < <(printf "%s\0" *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif *.tiff *.webp *.bmp | sort -Vz)
convert "${images[@]}" compilation_images.pdf
```

which uses the common trick of separating filenames with nul characters in order to safely handle whitespace when populating a `bash` array with sorted filenames.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am indeed on Linux, I forgot to mention it.
I tried the script, but it doesn't work on my side. What's weird is I get different errors on my two machines.
On my Arch Linux machine (everything up-to-date):

    sort: invalid option -- '0'

On my Fedora 34 machine (everything up-to-date):

    test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
    test.sh: line 7: `readarray -d '' -t images < <(printf "%s\0" *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif *.tiff *.webp *.bmp | sort -V0)'

Comment: My bad, it's `-z` not `-0`. I can never remember which program uses which.

Comment: The other error sounds like you're trying to use a shell other than bash, like dash or another one that sticks to posix sh features.

Comment: That's weird, I'm using bash on Fedora, and running the default GNOME version, with basically no tweak, and never installed any other shell on this machine.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. I was running the script using `sh script.sh`, assuming it would use bash as it's in the header of the script... Guess I still have a long way before I get the grasp of bash scripting.
Again, thanks a lot for the help, it'll save me countless hours in the future!