# Trying to use a variable in Single Quotes Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the variable $y in this snippet below but keep running into the filename showing up as $y.pdf

```
ls -v *.jpg | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\ $y.pdf/' | xargs convert
```

I've also tried the below:

```
ls -v *.jpg | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\'"$y.pdf"'/' | xargs convert

ls -v *.jpg | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\ {$y}.pdf/' | xargs convert
```

The top one usually fails, as sed is expecting something else. The bottom one just makes my filename {$y}.pdf.

Any ideas for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind the quoting problem; this is the wrong approach entirely. Just use a `for` loop to avoid all kinds of potential problems.

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    convert "$f" "${f%.jpg}.pdf"
done
```

`${f%.jpg}` expands to the name of the current file minus the `.jpg` extension.

To merge the files into one PDF is even simpler (I think):

```
convert *.jpg "$y.pdf"
```

---

Assuming `ls -v` outputs the file names in the correct order, and there aren't any of the usual concerns with parsing `ls` involved, use

```
ls -v *.jpg > input.txt
convert @input.txt "$y.pdf"
```

(There might be a way to avoid the use of a tempfile, maybe as simple as `ls -v *.jpg | convert @- "$y.pdf"`, but I'm too lazy to figure out all the ways `convert` can be called.)

Comment: I'm fairly certain I don't want this, only because I want to combine multiple .jpg files into ONE PDF, not each .jpg into a pdf.

Comment: To update on chepner's edit, it isn't this simple unfortunately. Maybe there could be a better way, though. In a nutshell I am combining multiple jpg's into one single PDF. The problem here is I have about ~10,000 files. Each named date-page 1, date-page 2, etc. The problem is that for some reason it isn't merging them properly as it's going Page 1, Page 10, Page 2, Page 20, etc. This is why I'm using ls -v. I searched around and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955425/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-images-to-a-pdf-from-the-command-line-on-linux#comment32682437_8955465).

Comment: And on his third edit... that actually worked. I think what I did before was convert input.txt file.pdf which tried to convert input.txt into a pdf. I guess I was missing the @. Thanks!

Comment: A sidenote as to why the ordering is so weird: ls outputs them in this way, you could say, that it outputs the files after sorting them alphabetically (1 comes before 2, thus first comes everything with a 1 at the beginning (1, 10, 11, ...).